# Can I catch pin to start event?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I build a tile image dynamically when the user presses the tile button in my application. But if the user clicks on pin to start from outside, how can I catch it and create a dynamic tile image? Is it possible or do I have to use a background agent?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to be notified that the user has pinned you to the Start screen until your code runs, either via Background Agent or regular App launch (at which point you simply query for your pinned tiles).